# Giving users control over SmartTarget Promotion Attributes?

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

SDL SmartTarget 2014 lets CMS users configure [promotions](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-9A7E4184-440C-4E00-9CEE-3E43AA7A80CF).

Can we filter or refine a Promotion based on Tridion attributes such as Component, Schema, or Component Template? *For SmartTarget 2014, would this be on the Tridion or Business Manager side?*.

I'd like CMS or Business Manager users to be able to control which Schemas and/or Component Templates should return in a given SmartTarget region.

**Edit**: made question clearer and specified the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Filtering and Ordering` section to filter on these attributes. Information about Schemas and Component Templates are automatically added by SmartTarget so you can directly filter on them in the editing screen for a Promotion.

You do need to ensure that they have been marked as "live" attributes in Fredhopper by adding them to the navigation index.

Relevant docs:

- [Filtering and ordering content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-09B2E4B8-AA87-4B45-9EF8-FBC85C0BA16E)
- [Adding attributes to the navigation index](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-EA86B8AA-6904-40AD-AF3A-AA7BC0ED1CD0)

Comment: Nice. I've seen Schemas and Component Templates in the (old) Business Manager, thanks for explaining how they work with ST 2014. Should I give JanH a chance to answer before accepting? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using the Filter option in Business Manager, users can filter by Template Title attribute, as well as Schema attribute for instance. So this would be a filter within a promotion, not at region level.

[image]

EDIT:
These filters are actually exposed in the ST 2014 interface.

Comment: Filtering options *are* available in SmartTarget 2014 in the Promotion editing screen.

Comment: Nice! I am still using a Beta version so I did not see them.